# How to change the JMenuBar text color?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, colors, jmenubar

I've been working on a project which uses Java's Swing class for the first time and I have been implementing a JMenuBar. I want the ability for users to swap color schemes, but I can't figure out how to swap the text color.

So far, I have attempted to set the JMenuBar to opaque, and setting the Foreground color to the color I want it to be (similar to how labels are used) using the `.setForeground()` method. When I used the `.setBackground()` method, it worked perfectly for the background of the JMenuBar..

Answer (score 3):

You would need to set the foreground of each `JMenu` that you add to the menu bar.

```
JMenu test = new JMenu("Testing");
test.setForeground( Color.RED );
menuBar.add(test);
```

Comment: @user21847419 you can mark the answer as "Accepted" by clicking on the "✔" sign if it solved your problem